# GridSearchCV not fetching mean_test_score in colab

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, gridsearchcv

I ran `randomForestClassifier` using `GridSearchCV` in colab.
However, `myGridSearchCV` does not return mean_test_score and shows it does not exists.
When I tried to check `clf.cv`*results* there is not mean_test_score.This works in Jupyter notebook not in Colab and I recently faced this issue.

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 120 out of 120 | elapsed: 25.3min finished
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-1d8f6c95affb> in <module>()
      7 clf.fit(X_tr, y_train)
      8 
----> 9 train_auc= clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
     10 cv_auc = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']

KeyError: 'mean_train_score'
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `clf` (not here, edit & update your post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are getting `mean_train_score` key error. Just set `return_train_score=True` in *gridsearchcv* parameters and it will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting that, you may still get the error with `mean_train_score` even if you have set `return_train_score=True` in the grid search, if you are using multiple scorers. Here is the reason. if you are running `GridSearchCV` with multiple scorers (e.g. you pass a parameter to the grid search such as in `scoring= {'Accuracy': 'accuracy', 'F1': 'f1_macro', 'AUC': 'roc_auc'}`) then you can expect that the `mean_train_score` variable name will depend on what you have set the `refit` to. For example, if you have set `refit='AUC'` then the appropriate variable name will then be `mean_train_AUC`, and others accordingly. These are very subtle changes that are documented in `scikit-learn` but can be painful to detect and deal with.

Answer (score -1):

> mean_train_score is missing you can cross verify this using
>
> `scores = rf.cv_results_`

`pd.DataFrame(scores).head()`

> rf is your gridsearchcv
>
> you will be getting error something like below
>
> KeyError: 'mean_train_score'
>
> solution
>
> **set return_train_score=True** in gridsearchcv
>
> `rf = GridSearchCV(rf, parameters, cv=n_folds,
>    scoring="accuracy",return_train_score=True)`

Comment: How's this different from the already accepted solution? And why you quote everything?

Comment: I am a very weak learner and very new to Machine Learning and Python and stackoverflow. I got the same problem and with the first answer i was not able to solve, I thought for people like me elaborated solution would help. I am sorry if i was wrong

Comment: But what you actually suggest is *exactly* the accepted answer, i.e. setting `return_train_score=True` in the GridSearchCV object - nothing different. How did *that* not worked for you in the first place?

Comment: In fact there *are* such terms, that's why comments & edits are here for - we are not supposed to use the answer space to comment or respond to *answers*. I can see your second point (and no, I am most certainly *not* a genius), but again, the answer says clearly "set `return_train_score=True` **in** gridsearchcv parameters". You are also expected to see that your post does not "look" right (you quote everything), and go back and remedy this. All these make a good case for downvoting (which is included in the terms, too). Happy to retract if you take the effort to improve your post...